# How to create correct entities mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I would like to use ORM Hibernate. And faced with issue below.
There are few tables that have translation on different languages. e.g. it looks like this:
[image]

In the database I can use join and get all required data 
e.g.:`SELECT * FROM car c
JOIN translation t on c.description = t.description
WHERE t.type = 'CAR'`

As you can see table 'translation' has column 'type' that uses for filtering by type.

**So the main question how to create correct entities and mapping?**

Comment: add more information about what you want and why city is required here

Comment: there are list of cities and list of cars. Each of them has translation of description on different languages in the table translation. I need to know hotw to create right POJO objects and entities mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A car has OneToMany translations. Similary a city has OneToMany translation. 
But every translation has zero to one car or zero to one city.

A translation is either for a Car or a City because its description talks about either City or Car. This is achieved by ManyToOne notation. There is no annotation in hibernate to explicitly say the range from Zero. Following is just to get an Fair Idea of mappings. I am not assuming any relation between City and Car even though I can think city has OneToMany cars.

```
@Entity
class Car
{
 private int Id;
 private String name;
 //.......... declare all  variables that you need
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car")
 private List<Translation>
 //getters and setters
 }

@Entity
class City
{
 private int Id;
 private String name;
 //.......... declare all  variables that you need
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city")
 private List<Translation>
 //getters and setters
 }   

@Entity
class Translation
{
 private int Id;
 private String language;
 //.......... declare all  variables that you need
 @ManyToOne
 private Car;
 @ManyToOne
 private City;
 //getters and setters
 }
```

Comment: Your example is not comleted, you should use '@JoinTable' annotation for mapping relations and '@Table' for set table name. Also there is no trivial mapping by id so example below is not well for my task. In my case this little bit similar with hibernate inheritance namely DiscriminatorColumn and DiscriminatorValue. But I can not use inheritants becouse owerriding id is not allowed. From code side this is simple association but I do not know how to map it.

Comment: I just gave a brief code which can be improvised further based on your explanation.